# Vue: Can't display Javascript Map with keys and values using v-for :key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Json like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":"big"
      },
      "2":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":"big"
      },
      "3":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":"big"
      },
      "4":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":"big"
      },
      "5":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":"big"
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to display just numbers `1,2,3,5` using this:

```
<div v-for = "pos in this.breakdown" :key = "pos">
            <p>{{pos}}</p>
</div>
```

But it displayed the values instead:

```
{ "color": "red", "size": "big" }

{ "color": "red", "size": "big" }

{ "color": "red", "size": "big" }

{ "color": "red", "size": "big" }

{ "color": "red", "size": "big" }
```

I tried to display it after converting it to a Javascript's Map of Maps:

```
function jsonToMap(jsonString)  {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var dataObject = jsonObject.data;
    var dataMap = new Map(Object.entries(dataObject));
    var resultMap = new Map();
    for (const pos of dataMap.keys())  {
        console.log(pos);
        var posMap = new Map(Object.entries(dataMap.get(pos)));
        resultMap.set(pos, posMap);
    }

    console.log("done!");
    return resultMap;
}
```

```
<div v-for = "number in this.breakdownTable" :key = "number">
  <p>Number: {{number}}</p>

  <div v-for = "pair in this.breakdownTable" :key = "pair.number">
     <p>{{pair}} = {{this.breakdownTable.get(number).get(pair)}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it wouldn't display anything.

**ANSWER**: Adri1's answer helped and I wrote this:

```
        <div v-for="(obj, pos) in this.breakdown" :key="pos">
            <p>{{ pos }}: </p>

            <div v-for = "(obj2, pos2) in obj" :key="pos2">
                <p>{{obj2}} = {{pos2}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

that produced this:

```
1:

red = color

big = size

2:

red = color

big = size

3:

red = color

big = size

4:

red = color

big = size

5:

red = color

big = size
```

Comment: you could insert `index` in `v-for`，like `v-for = "(pos,index) in this.breakdown"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in a `v-for` loop, you can provide a second optional argument to get the **index** of the item you're iterating on:

```js
"data": {
  "items": [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3'
  ]
}
```

```html
<div v-for = "(item, index) in items">
   {{ index }} : {{ item }}
</div>
```

Will output:

```
0 : item 1 
1 : item 2 
2 : item 3
```

Now adapted to your example:

*With unknown object indexes*

```html
<div v-for="(obj, pos) in this.breakdown" :key="pos">
    <p>{{ pos }}: </p>

    <div v-for="(obj2, pos2) in obj" :key="pos2">
        <p>{{ obj2 }} = {{ pos2 }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See more `v-for` possibilities in the official documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: I edited my question with my final answer, it might help future readers if you'd included it in your answer